# Setting Class values in constructor to parameters

Tags: javascript, class

I have this code, which is kinda long winded but gets there in the end …

```
class WorksButLongWinded {
  constructor (callback, params = {}) {
    // defaults ...
    this.foo = "string";
    this.bar = 200;

    this.callback = callback;

    // params ...
    if( typeof params.foo != "undefined" ) { this.foo = params.foo }
    if( typeof params.bar != "undefined" ) { this.bar = params.bar }
  }
}
```

I thought I might try using destructuring to speed things along, like this:

```
class DoesNotWork {
  constructor (callback, params = {}) {
    {
      this.foo = "string", 
      this.bar = 200
    } = params;

    this.callback = callback;

  }
}
```

... except that doesn't work. It doesn't even pass syntax muster.

What is a clean and simple way of writing a class constructor that takes an optional `params` object with various optional parameters that override some default values?

Comment: do you mean you want to destructure params ?

Comment: @ShubhamGupta umm ... yes? I think that's what it is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```js
class WorksButLongWinded {
  constructor(callback, params) {
    let defaults = {
      foo: "string",
      bar: 200
    };

    this.callback = callback;
    Object.assign(this, defaults, params);
  }
}

let a = new WorksButLongWinded(() => {});
console.log(a.foo);  // "string"
console.log(a.bar);  // "200"

let b = new WorksButLongWinded(() => {}, {foo: "bar"});
console.log(b.foo);  // "bar"
console.log(b.bar);  // "200"
```

`Object.assign` does exactly what you want.

Comment: ooh, `Object.assign` looks useful

Comment: I like this solution. I just learnt .assign() could save a lot of typing like `Object.keys().forEach(...)`. An approach I was going to post.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you are destructuring is incorrect. Try the below code where we destructure from params and then assign the values to this.

```
class WorksButLongWinded {
  constructor (callback, params = {}) {
    const {foo = "string", bar = 200} = params;
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
    this.callback = callback;
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, that is shorter (coding the defaults into the destructure and then assigning those values)

Comment: @Erics yes that way it is cleaner as well.